# Excel Shuts down immediately after open for one user, not all

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

The user is a regular user of Excel. Everytime he starts any excel file or just the program itself, the window pops up that says an error has occured and ask if he would like to recover his work. Regardless whether it is checked or not the program restarts and the same issue occurs. The same happens if he does or does not send the report to Microsoft. I know that this is a profile based issue in a domain environment, but how could I fix it without creating a new user profile?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/startupproblems.asp) a good link that might help you troubleshoot the problem.
It might be an addin or hidden workbook that is causing problems.  For example, the link suggests trying:

> Click Start, Run,
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.exe" /Automation
>
> Quotes mandatory, Note you may have to change the path.
>
> If your error disappears, either an add-in or a (hidden) workbook that is loaded upon Excel's start bothers you.

Comment: oh, hehe, just noticed this is a year ago, so you probably don't care anymore...